# How to downgrade glassfish from 4.1.1 to 4.1 in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

A pretty simple question here:

I need to downgrade the version of Glassfish I am using in Eclipse Luna from 4.1.1 to 4.1, to get over an extremely annoying bug that occurs when trying to POST/PUT using JAX-RS.

I've looked on-line but have been unable to find out how to revert to the previous version - can anybody tell me how to do this, or point to instructions somewhere on the web for how to do it? I am pretty new to glassfish and eclipse....

All help greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can downgrade an installed server from eclipse same way you don't have an option in server's settings to downgrade it to another version. You must set a new server configuration.

First of all you must install on your computer the new Glassfish server you need (this installation is a required step).

Once done, to set another version on your ide you must go to Eclipse's options and select **Window / Preferences / Server / Runtime Environment** and select the right **Add** button

[image]

After that, select Glassfish folder and Glassfish 4 version. Check also the **Create new local server** checkbox
[image]

With this option, eclipse will allow you to select another Glassfish installation to be added. You should have the 4.1.1 version you need installed previously.

After that, open your eclipse's servers tab (you probably know how to access it but, if not, it's at eclipse's Window / Show view / Other / Server / Servers ) and do right click and select New / Server

[image]

Add your new configurated server and enjoy.